# Control the row returned on a group by that matches the result

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
 ----------------------------
|  id  |  product  |  price  |
 ----------------------------
|  1   |  1        |  50     |
|  2   |  1        |  39     |
|  3   |  1        |  60     |
 ----------------------------
```

What I need is to get the lowest price (39) grouped by product (1) and keep the id of the lowest price.

I have this query

```
SELECT
    id,
    product,
    MIN(price) AS price
FROM
    variant
GROUP BY
    product
```

That results on

```
 ----------------------------
|  id  |  product  |  price  |
 ----------------------------
|  1   |  1        |  39     |
 ----------------------------
```

But the result I'm looking for is

```
 ----------------------------
|  id  |  product  |  price  |
 ----------------------------
|  2   |  1        |  39     |
 ----------------------------
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

I've made a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2ddb2

Answer (score 0):

try: (not very elegant but a good platform to make further changes)

```
select A.*,B.id from 
(SELECT product,MIN(price) AS minprice 
FROM variant GROUP BY product ) A
inner join 
(SELECT * FROM variant ) B
on A.product = B.product and A.minprice = B.price
```

Comment: This works, but i need to put it into a views and i cant because of se select inside the from

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the id by x (like 1000000 depending on limit of id) and add it to the price. Then take the min and split out the id later. It's kinda backwoods but should work.

`SELECT
    product,
    MIN(price+(id/10000)) AS price
FROM
    variant
GROUP BY
    product`